# How to close soft keyboard and have a possibility to determine cursor position

Tags: android, keyboard, cursor

How to close soft keyboard and have a possibility to determine cursor position by touching place in EditText?

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

It's hide soft keyboard but i can't set cursor! How solve that problem?

Comment: And How find place? where i touch&

Answer (score 0):

Use [Selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html) to set the cursor position and use [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29) method

Comment: And How find place? where i touch&